# ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, machine-learning, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to make a 'matplotlib' graph out of the following equation : q(x) = (x**2) / (x+1)

I tried this code :

```
def r(x):
    return (x*x) / (x+1)

while x<= -2 | x >= 0:
    pylab.plot(x, r(x), color = 'r--')
```

Which shows me the error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-387fb2375bb1> in <module>
      2     return (x*x) / (x+1)
      3 
----> 4 while x<= -2 | x >= 0:
      5     pylab.plot(x, r(x), color = 'r--')

TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I'm new to Machine Learning with python, so I have very little knowledge on how to debug this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`|` is bitwise or operator - you should use simply `or` keyword for logical alternative.

[Read further](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).